# Can't install ElastAlert on elasticsearch6.1.1 by "python-dateutil 2.7.0"

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch, python-dateutil, elastalert

My enviroment:

os:ubuntu 16.04

python:2.7.12

elasticsearch:6.1.1

I want to install elasalert0.1.29 by "python setup.py install",but I got this wrong:

```
error: python-dateutil 2.7.0 is installed but python-dateutil<2.7.0,>=2.1 is required by set(['botocore'])
```

Anyone can give me some advise?thanks a lot!

Comment: thank you for your reply but I have upgrated to the latest version 2.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like python-dateutil should be below your installed version 2.7.0

Are you using pip? Maybe try installing an older version:

```
pip uninstall python-dateutil
pip install python-dateutil==2.6.1
```